# How to use Hazelcast as a message queue beetwen multi server?

Tags: message-queue, messaging, hazelcast

I'm trying to use HazelCast as a message queue.
I run hazelcast as a standalone server.
And I have 2 hazelcast clients: Server1 and Server2.
I want to send messages beetwen Server1 and Server2.
At server1, I have:

```
public class ClusterManager implements MessageListener {
    static ITopic topicServer1;
    static ITopic topicServer2;

    public static void init() {
        ClusterManager cluster = new ClusterManager();

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
        HazelcastInstance hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);

        topicServer2 = hazelcastClient.getTopic("server2");
        topicServer2.addMessageListener(cluster);


        topicServer1 = hazelcastClient.getTopic("server1");
        topicServer1.publish("this is test msg from Server1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        String data = (String) message.getMessageObject();
        Debug.trace("onMessage", data);
        topicLobby.publish("this is test msg from Server2");
    }
}
```

On server2, I have:

```
public class ClusterManager implements MessageListener {
        static ITopic topicServer1;
        static ITopic topicServer2;

        public static void init() {
            ClusterManager cluster = new ClusterManager();

            ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
            config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
            HazelcastInstance hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);

            topicServer1 = hazelcastClient.getTopic("server1");
            topicServer1.addMessageListener(cluster);


            topicServer2 = hazelcastClient.getTopic("server2");
            topicServer2.publish("this is test msg from Server2");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            String data = (String) message.getMessageObject();
            Debug.trace("onMessage", data);
            topicLobby.publish("this is test msg from Server1");
        }
    }
```

But when I run 2 servers, CPU usages are very high.
What is right way to use hazelcast for this case?

Thanks

Comment: 2 servers as in 2 Hazelcast nodes? And what is calling the `init` method? Guess you might call it in a loop and recreate the HazelcastClient over and over again?

Comment: 2 servers are 2 hazelcast clients only. init method is called 1 time in the main method.

Comment: Can you create a small app to reproduce the issue? Thanks.